# Grow LinearLayout on swipe then it becomes sticky header

Tags: android, animation, layout, android-linearlayout

I have unique situation here where I want to grow a `LinearLayout` when a user swipes up, it will grow as so in this image and then become a sticky header at the top of the phone:

[image: animated_layout]

How would I go about doing this with best practices? Should I create a custom class called `onSwipeListener` which would extend `onTouchListener`? Or should I go about doing this in a different manner?

Appreciate any feedback at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Parallax effect, check out this:
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-header-parallax-with-sticky-view-in-android

Comment: Please don't answer a One-Link answer.